# Changing excel cell color using vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, colors

hello guys i asked this question before but i just don't seem to find an answer can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong in my code because even while i tried every methode on the internet no change is ever made on my excel file this my code for changing the color of a cell on an existing excel file

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim ws1 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
        Dim xlApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        ws1 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(TextBox1.Text).Worksheets(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
        Dim rangeToFormat As Excel.Range
        rangeToFormat = ws1.Cells(6, 5)
        rangeToFormat.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Red)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim xlworkbook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
        Dim xlApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        TextBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

        xlworkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(TextBox1.Text, 0, True)

        For Each xlWorkSheet In xlApp.Sheets
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(xlWorkSheet.Name)
        Next
    End Sub
```

my code asks the user to choose an excel file, choose the worksheet that wants to work on and then click on a button to change the color of the cell(6,5) and other cells that i didn't add here to make my code easier to undrestand. thank you sooo much guys on advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ws1 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xlApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    ws1 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(TextBox1.Text).Worksheets(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
    Dim rangeToFormat As Excel.Range
    rangeToFormat = ws1.Cells(6, 5)
    rangeToFormat.Font.Color = RGB(255, 20, 20)

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim xlworkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xlApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    TextBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

    xlworkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(TextBox1.Text, 0, True)

    For Each xlWorkSheet In xlApp.Sheets
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(xlWorkSheet.Name)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: @DarrenPeterson thank you darren so mch for the suggestion but i don't thing that's the problem because i tried that and that also doesn't work. i guess i need to save the changes to the excel file that is in textbox1 can you suggest me how we save them ? an thank you sooo much for your time

Answer (score 0):

for the one that are still looking for the answer i actually did find it you should just add after the color command:

```
        xlWb.Save()
        xlApp.Quit()
        xlApp = Nothing
```